# How do you install skins on Steam?

Tags: steam

I've seen people who have had customized versions of the Steam application, usually with different graphics or stylings.

How is this done?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Since you probably don't have any skins installed, you'll want to first find a skin online.  Skins can be easily found online, either through a quick Google search, or a search through the Steam Users' Forums and other gaming forum sites.

Some popular Steam skins:

- [Metro](http://metroforsteam.com/)

[image]

- [Air](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2989566)

[image]

- [Pixelvision](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1914848)

[image]

- [Steam Compact](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1279345)

The basic [gist of installing skins](http://www.pcgamer.com/2014/06/16/the-best-steam-skins/):

> - Download the skin files.
> - Extract and drop them into your Steam skins folder in your Steam directory. `C: -> Program Files -> Steam -> Skins`.
>     [image]
> - Head to the Interface section of your Steam Settings.
>
>   [image]
> - Pick the skin you want from the "select the skin you wish Steam to use" drop down menu.
>     [image]
> - Restart Steam.

Comment: +1 for Metro for Steam. As a side note, those really are the only three decent skins at the time of writing, so don't bother looking much further.

Comment: @Keavon to each their own. I picked ones with clean, concise UIs, nothing more.

Comment: Of course nearly everything is an opinion, but few would dispute the opinion that, to be decent, interfaces shouldn't be ugly, jumbled, and messy, which all other skins beside those three generally are. Citing [this PC Gamer article](http://pcgamer.com/2014/06/16/the-best-steam-skins/2) listing them in that order, the three you mentioned in your answer would be generally considered the only three good-looking, non-messy ones. Steam Compact may also be useful for people with small screens, but its lack of padding makes its usability a bit less pleasant. I doubt many would dispute these claims.

Comment: `.local/share/Steam/Skins` for gnu/linux steam

Answer (score 6):

To install skins on Steam, you simply drag the skin's folder into the skins folder in your Steam install directory.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\skins\...
```

You can get some skins from some of these sites:
http://bit.ly/Z9fLZr - I Googled "Steam Skins"
http://www.metroforsteam.com/ - Steam Metro Skin
just to name a few. There are others found all over the internet. There should be a few on Daviant Art too.

---

To activate a skin, ensure that the skin's folder is dragged into your Steam "skins" folder.
Then, go to `Steam > Settings > Interface` and change the skin you want to use.
Then, restart Steam for the changes to appear (your newly selected skin to show/display).

---

As for how to make skins, that's complicated. More on that later when I get the time to complete.
I found this: http://www.scribd.com/doc/87688286/Guide-How-to-Make-a-Steam-Skin-2 (not by me), but should explain how to make skins.