# How to install a Steam Skin on Mac OS?

Tags: steam

I know there already is [a question on how to install Steam Skins](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/183191/167694), but all answers there are for Windows only, so **can you explain how to install a Steam Skin on Mac OS?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this](http://www.jasonchen.org/log/2011/05/how-to-install-steam-skin-on-mac/) will be helpfull but will post it below to let you not click on any links. point 6 there is useless.

1. Navigate to Steam.app in Finder. Right-click it and select ‘Show
   Package Contents’.
2. Go to ‘Contents/MacOS/skins’.
3. Copy the folder which directly contains your desired skin.
4. Paste the skin into Steam.app’s skins directory.
5. Go to your settings in steam and under skins you can set the skin you want

Comment: The article you linked is a bit outdated (2011). You should be able to set the skin (step 6) directly from the Steam settings

Comment: Ah fair enough, I'll change it